# Text inside div overflows in Mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

The text inside my div overflows from the columns for a certain mobile device size. It works perfectly for any browser and other mobile devices except for 768x1024 in landscape.

I used this bootstrap div:

```html
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
```

This is what it looks like on that mobile device:
[image]

That's the only resolution that it happens like that. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you complete your question and put your code on https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: you have to post full html